# Highlight duplicates of cell in real time -- is there an addon for this?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to identify duplicates in Excel. I can highlight all duplicates in a column, using standard excel tools.

Ideally I would like to, say, click in cell A3 and have excel instantaneously highlight all instances in column A, which are duplicates of A3. This should happen in "real-time".

Comment: Excel's Conditional Formatting feature makes it easy to identify duplicate values in a list: [Find and remove duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d). Anything doing that on every cell selection change in "real-time" will slow your Excel down a lot. Depending on the amount of data it won't be usable anymore.

Comment: Here is another good resource with many examples: [How to find duplicates in Excel: identify, highlight count, filter, and more](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/03/02/identify-duplicates-excel/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a VBA solution to this problem you could try the below, but as noted already by PEH this would not be ideal with a large amount of data.

This would have to be applied to the sheet you're using and assumes that you're only assessing Column A.

Note: It will check Column A any time a cell on the sheet is double clicked...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'Name your sheet here
SheetName = "Sheet1"

'Work out how many rows there are in Column A
LastRow = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Copy current value to check later
CheckValue = Selection.Value


    'Validate there is more than 1 filled cell
    If LastRow > 1 Then

        'Redim an array to hold all Column A data then load it to the array
        ReDim DataArray(1 To LastRow) As Variant
        DataArray = Range(Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(SheetName).Cells(LastRow, 1))

        'Clear previous highlighting
        Range(Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(SheetName).Cells(LastRow, 1)).Interior.Pattern = xlNone

        'loop through array highlighting cells that match the "CheckValue"
        For I = 1 To LastRow

            If DataArray(I, 1) = CheckValue Then

                Sheets(SheetName).Cells(I, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

            End If

        Next I

    End If

End Sub
```

It's likely a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: works great, but I understand about performance being an issue... thanks anyways, it helped to speed up things!

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty, place this in the wanted sheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim cellsToHighlight As Range, cell As Range
    Set cellsToHighlight = Range("B1")
    For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If cell.Value2 = Target.Value2 Then Set cellsToHighlight = Union(cellsToHighlight, cell)
    Next
    Set cellsToHighlight = Intersect(cellsToHighlight, Columns(1))
    If Not cellsToHighlight Is Nothing Then cellsToHighlight.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formating for "Duplicate Values"
[image]